# Reading outgoing packets from selected process

Tags: c#, tcp, packet-capture

Is it possible to read outgoing packets from selected process in C#? If yes, what api should I use?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read [faq] and [ask] a couple of times..

Comment: check that http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2614/Testing-TCP-and-UDP-socket-servers-using-C-and-NET

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're trying to do something similar to *WireShark* or *Winsock Packet Editor*.

The short answer is **no**. There's definitely no namespace or assembly with the functionality built-in.

The long answer is **yes, but you'll have to get your hands a little dirty.** You will more than likely have to make a *C++ DLL* to inject into the process to 'spy' on it. However, you can interface this *DLL* via *C#* and make your interface all in *.NET*.

Your first step would be to create the *C++ DLL*, which would just need a few exports:

```
bool InitialzeHook()
{
  // TODO: Patch the Import Address Table (IAT) to overwrite
  //       the address of Winsock's send/recv functions
  //       with your SpySend/SpyRecv ones instead.
}

bool UninitializeHook()
{
  // TODO: Restore the Import Address Table (IAT) to the way you found it.
}

// This function will be called instead of Winsock's recv function once hooked.
int SpySend(SOCKET s, const char *buf, int len, int flags)
{
  // TODO: Do something with the data to be sent, like logging it.

  // Call the real Winsock send function.
  int numberOfBytesSent = send(s, buf, len, flags);

  // Return back to the calling process.
  return numberOfBytesSent;
}

// This function will be called instead of Winsock's recv function once hooked.
int SpyRecv(SOCKET s, char *buf, int len, int flags)
{
  // Call the real Winsock recv function to get the data.
  int numberOfBytesReceived = recv(s, buf, len, flags);

  // TODO: Do something with the received data, like logging it.

  // Return back to the calling process.
  return numberOfBytesReceived;
}
```

The most difficult part of this all is the function that will patch the **Import Address Table** (IAT). There are various resources on how to traverse it and find function imports inside of it. **TIP:** You will have to patch *Winsock* imports by **ordinal**, not name.

Check out [Inside the Windows PE Format (Part 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx) and [C++ Code Example](http://www.governmentsecurity.org/forum/topic/32819-printing-import-table-pe-file-format/).

Once you have all that done, you'll have to inject the *DLL* you made into the target process. Here is the *C++* psuedo-code to do that (off the top of my head):

```
// Get the target window handle (if you don't have the process ID handy).
HWND hWnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "Your Target Window Name");

// Get the process ID from the target window handle.
DWORD processId = 0;
DWORD threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &processId);

// Open the process for reading/writing memory.
DWORD accessFlags = PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | 
                    PROCESS_VM_READ | 
                    PROCESS_VM_WRITE | 
                    PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION;

HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(accessFlags, false, processId);

// Get the base address for Kernel32.dll (always the same for each process).
HMODULE hKernel32 = GetModuleHandleA("kernel32");

// Get the address of LoadLibraryA (always the same for each process).
DWORD loadLibraryAddr = GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "LoadLibraryA");

// Allocate some space in the remote process and write the library string to it.
LPVOID libraryNameBuffer = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, 256, 
                                          MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE,
                                          PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

LPCSTR libraryName = L"MySpyLibrary.dll\0";
DWORD numberOfBytesWritten = 0;
BOOL writeResult = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, libraryNameBuffer,
                                                (LPCVOID)libraryName,
                                                strlen(libraryName) + 1,
                                                &numberOfBytesWritten);

// Create a thread in the remote process, using LoadLibraryA as the procedure,
// and the parameter is the library name we just wrote to the remote process.
DWORD remoteThreadId = 0;
HANDLE hRemoteThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0,
                                          (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)loadLibraryAddr,
                                          libraryNameBuffer,
                                          0, &remotThreadId);

// Wait for our thread to complete and get the exit code (which is the return value).
DWORD loadedLibraryAddr = 0;
BOOL waitResult = WaitForSingleObject(hRemoteThread, INFINITE); 
BOOL exitResult = GetExitCodeThread(hRemoteThread, &loadedLibraryAddr);

// TODO: Check that it was loaded properly
// if(lodadedLibraryAddr == NULL) { ... }

// Cleanup our loose ends here.
VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, libraryNameBuffer, 256, MEM_RELEASE);
CloseHandle(hRemoteThread);
CloseHandle(hProcess);
```

You can do the same thing via *C# platform invoke* (pInvoke) though. It's up to you how you want to log and transmit the data back to your *C#* monitoring program. You could use some *interprocess communication* like [Named Pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `NamedPipeClientStream` in *C#*.

However, this will do it and the beautiful part is that it will work for nearly any program. This same technique can be applied for any type of sniffing, not just *Winsock*.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can... but only if the process has a "public hook" to it's listener. Otherwise, you would have to create a sniffer: debugging the executable, finding the offset of the socket send buffer and hooking a reader to it. Easier to do it though a firewall-like application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TPL dataflow to do that.